# what is the difference between unicode characters starting from `\U` and `\u` in python utf-8 characters support

Tags: python, mysql

I have 2 strings, both of which translates to the same thing in the end but in one of the representation, mysql adds the data to the db; in other, it doesn't.

1. `\ud83c\uddfa\ud83c\uddf8`
2. `\U0001f1fa\U0001f1f8`

I am not able to figure out the difference between these two representations and the reason for 1 format supporting data addition in mysql.
Mysql connection is open in utf-8 mode.

Comment: The biggest difference here is the *double backslash* vs. *one backslash*. Can you give more context how this is used…?

Comment: updated! it was a typo

Answer (score 2):

`\U` is 32-bit and followed with 8 hex digits, when `\u` is 16-bit and followed by 4 digits. See 'https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html' for example.